# Unable to start nfsen service in centos7

Tags: centos7

NFSEN was working perfect on my centos7 system. now facing issue post restart the server. when i trying to start nfsen service it showing "Can't kill a non-numeric process ID at/opt/nfsen/libexec/NfSenRC.pm line 203."

Solution i tried.
1. tried restarting server multiple times.
2. tried copy new nfsen service file in /etc/init.d/
3. tried /etc/init.d/nfsen reconfig
please help.

regards,
Narendra

Answer (score 3):

From the code:

```
    if ( -f "$NfConf::PIDDIR/nfsend.pid" ) {
            open PID, "$NfConf::PIDDIR/nfsend.pid" ||
                    die "Can't read pid file '$NfConf::PIDDIR/nfsend.pid': $!\n";
            my $pid = <PID>;
            chomp $pid;
            close PID;
```

So try removing the "nfsend.pid" which probably resides in **/opt/nfsen/var/run/nfsend.pid**